# Error running cap deploy:cold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano

I am trying to host my first rails app but i am having the following errors.

```
    servers: ["208.68.37.172"]
    [208.68.37.172] executing command
    command finished in 1098ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing "cd /home/deployer/apps/cf/current && env RBENV_VERSION=\"1.9.3-p194\" /home/deployer/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile --trace"
    servers: ["208.68.37.172"]
    [208.68.37.172] executing command
 ** [out :: 208.68.37.172] sh: 1: cd:
 ** [out :: 208.68.37.172] can't cd to /home/deployer/apps/cf/current
 ** [out :: 208.68.37.172] 
    command finished in 1660ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deployer/apps/cf/releases/20121117131510; true"
    servers: ["208.68.37.172"]
    [208.68.37.172] executing command
    command finished in 2548ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/cf/current && env RBENV_VERSION=\"1.9.3-p194\" /home/deployer/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile --trace'" on 208.68.37.172
```

my deploy.rb is below

```
require 'capistrano-rbenv'
require "bundler/capistrano"


server "208.68.37.172", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "cf"
set :user, "deployer"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false



set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:ramza1/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  namespace :assets do
    task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      run "cd #{current_path} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile --trace"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"


end
```

my unicorn.rb is below

```
root = "/home/deployer/apps/cf/current"
working_directory root
pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.blog.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 30
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.cf.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name completefashiononline.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/cf/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

unicorn_init.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Manage unicorn server
# Description:       Start, stop, restart unicorn server for a specific application.
### END INIT INFO
set -e

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/home/deployer/apps/cf/current
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
AS_USER=deployer
set -u

OLD_PIN="$PID.oldbin"

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PIN && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PIN`
}

run () {
  if [ "$(id -un)" = "$AS_USER" ]; then
    eval $1
  else
    su -c "$1" - $AS_USER
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
  sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
stop)
  sig QUIT && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
force-stop)
  sig TERM && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
restart|reload)
  sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
upgrade)
  if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
  then
    n=$TIMEOUT
    while test -s $OLD_PIN && test $n -ge 0
    do
      printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
    done
    echo

    if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $OLD_PIN
    then
      echo >&2 "$OLD_PIN still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
      exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
  fi
  echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
reopen-logs)
  sig USR1
  ;;
*)
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

This is all i have used. pls any help to fix this will be great. Thank You

Comment: seems that there is sth wrong with the precompile task. Can you run the last command on the server with the same user from the deployment? Maybe this gives you a better output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are running your assets precompile task is running right after deploy:update_code. At this point there is no "current" directory inside the base_path. Which is why you are getting that error.

You should change it so that the assets:precompile task runs after deploy:finalize_update or better yet, use the in built asset precompilation.

You can do that by adding this to your Capfile:

```
load 'deploy/assets'
```

Comment: Hi, I met this problem as well. However, `load 'deploy/assets'` has already been added in my Capfile. Is there any things I should check?

Comment: @GaryLai Hi, are you getting the exact same error? If not, do let me know and I'll try to help. If you are getting the exact same error, what version of cap are u using?